# How to explode a Bengali text using PHP to save all content to Database?

Tags: php, mysql, string, split, explode

I have a file (.txt) full of content and it contains Bengali and Arabic, I want to split (explode) the contents of that file then insert it into a database.

I did this before for English and Persian, but I don't know why PHP doesn't know Bengali.

**Some text of that file:**

> ১। গৃহ যুদ্ধের সময় উষ্ট্র শাবকের মতো হয়ে যেয়ো, যার পিঠ এমন শক্ত নয়
>   যাতে চড়া যায় অথবা বাট এমন নয় যা দোহন করা যায়।
>
> 1- قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) : كُنْ فِي الْفِتْنَةِ كَابْنِ اللَّبُونِ لَا
>   ظَهْرٌ فَيُرْكَبَ وَ لَا ضَرْعٌ فَيُحْلَبَ
>
> ২। যে লোভে অভ্যস্ত হয়ে পড়ে সে নিজেকে অবমূল্যায়ন করে, যে নিজের অভাব
>   অনটনের কথা প্রকাশ করে সে নিজকে অবমানিত করে, আর যার জিহবা আত্মাকে
>   পরাভূত করে তার আত্মা দুষিত হয়ে পড়ে।
>
> 2- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) : أَزْرَى بِنَفْسِهِ مَنِ اسْتَشْعَرَ
>   الطَّمَعَ.وَ رَضِيَ بِالذُّلِّ مَنْ كَشَفَ عَنْ ضُرِّهِ. وَ هَانَتْ
>   عَلَيْهِ نَفْسُهُ مَنْ أَمَّرَ عَلَيْهَا لِسَانَهُ.
>
> ৩। কৃপণতা লজ্জা এবং কাপুরুষতা ত্রুটি। আর দারিদ্র একজন বুদ্ধিমান লোককেও
>   তার নিজের বেলায় যুক্তি প্রদর্শন করতে ব্যর্থ করে এবং দুঃস্থ ব্যক্তি তার
>   নিজের শহরেও আগন্তুকের মত।
>
> 3- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) : الْبُخْلُ عَارٌ وَ الْجُبْنُ مَنْقَصَةٌ وَ
>   الْفَقْرُ يُخْرِسُ الْفَطِنَ عَنْ حُجَّتِهِ وَ الْمُقِلُّ غَرِيبٌ فِي
>   بَلْدَتِهِ
>
> ৪। অযোগ্যতা বজ্রাঘাত, ধৈর্য সাহসিকতা, মিতাচার ধন-সম্পদ, আত্মপ্রত্যয়
>   বর্ম এবং সর্বোত্তম সাথি হলো আল্লাহর ইচ্ছায় সমর্পিত হওয়া।
>
> 4- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) : الْعَجْزُ آفَةٌ وَ الصَّبْرُ شَجَاعَةٌ  وَ
>   الزُّهْدُ ثَرْوَةٌ وَ الْوَرَعُ جُنَّةٌ وَ نِعْمَ الْقَرِينُ الرِّضَى
>
> ৫। জ্ঞান শ্রদ্ধাস্পদ সম্পত্তি, সদাচারণ নতুন পোষাক এবং চিন্তা স্বচ্ছ
>   আয়না।
>
> 5- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام):الْعِلْمُ وِرَاثَةٌ كَرِيمَةٌ وَ الْآدَابُ
>   حُلَلٌ مُجَدَّدَةٌ وَ الْفِكْرُ مِرْآةٌ صَافِيَةٌ
>
> ৬। জ্ঞানীদের বক্ষ তার গুপ্ত বিষয়ের সিন্দুক, প্রফুল্লতা বন্ধুত্বের
>   বন্ধন এবং কার্যকর ধৈর্য সকল দোষত্রুটির কবর।
>
> 6- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام): صَدْرُ الْعَاقِلِ صُنْدُوقُ سِرِّهِ وَ
>   الْبَشَاشَةُ حِبَالَةُ الْمَوَدَّةِ وَ الِاحْتِمَالُ قَبْرُ
>   الْعُيُوبِ‏ئ {وَ رُوِيَ أَنَّهُ قَالَ فِي الْعِبَارَةِ عَنْ هَذَا
>   الْمَعْنَى أَيْضاً الْمَسْأَلَةُ خِبَاءُ الْعُيُوبِ وَ مَنْ رَضِيَ
>   عَنْ نَفْسِهِ كَثُرَ السَّاخِطُ عَلَيْهِ}.
>
> ৭। বদান্যতা কার্যকর চিকিৎসা, এ জীবনের আমল পরকালে চোখের সামনে দেখতে
>   পাবে।
>
> 7- وَ الصَّدَقَةُ دَوَاءٌ مُنْجِحٌ    وَ أَعْمَالُ الْعِبَادِ فِي
>   عَاجِلِهِمْ نُصْبُ أَعْيُنِهِمْ فِي آجَالِهِمْ
>
> ৮। মানুষ কী আশ্চর্যজনক যে, সে চর্বি আর এক টুরকা মাংস দ্বারা কথা বলে,
>   একটা হাড় দ্বারা শুনে এবং একটা ছিদ্র দ্বারা শ্বাস-প্রশ্বাস নেয়।
>
> 8- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) :اعْجَبُوا لِهَذَا الْإِنْسَانِ يَنْظُرُ
>   بِشَحْمٍ وَ يَتَكَلَّمُ بِلَحْمٍ وَ يَسْمَعُ بِعَظْمٍ وَ يَتَنَفَّسُ
>   مِنْ خَرْمٍ.
>
> ৯। কারো ভাগ্য সুপ্রসন্ন হলে পৃথিবী যখন অনুকূলে আসে তখন অন্যের ভালো
>   কাজের সুকীর্তি তার নামে হয়, আর পৃথিবী প্রতিকূলে গেলে নিজের ভালো কাজের
>   সুনাম থেকে সে বঞ্চিত হয়।
>
> 9- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام)إِذَا أَقْبَلَتِ الدُّنْيَا عَلَى أَحَدٍ
>   أَعَارَتْهُ مَحَاسِنَ غَيْرِهِ وَ إِذَا أَدْبَرَتْ عَنْهُ سَلَبَتْهُ
>   مَحَاسِنَ نَفْسِهِ.
>
> ১০। মানুষের সাথে দেখা হলে এমন আচরণ করবে যেন তোমার মৃত্যুতে তারা কাঁদে
>   এবং তুমি বেঁচে থাকলে তারা তোমার দীর্ঘায়ূ কামনা করে।
>
> 10- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام):خَالِطُوا النَّاسَ مُخَالَطَةً إِنْ مِتُّمْ
>   مَعَهَا بَكَوْا عَلَيْكُمْ وَ إِنْ عِشْتُمْ حَنُّوا إِلَيْكُمْ.
>
> ১১। প্রতিপক্ষের ওপর জয়ী হলে তাকে ক্ষমা করো।
>
> 11- وَ قَالَ (عليه‏السلام) : إِذَا قَدَرْتَ عَلَى عَدُوِّكَ فَاجْعَلِ
>   الْعَفْوَ عَنْهُ شُكْراً لِلْقُدْرَةِ عَلَيْهِ

I am going to [pipe character](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0239/2809/files/Pipe_Mac.jpg?1239) to explode *(as you can see at the end of all Bengali sentences there is a **|** what call it pipe)*

and When I copy that pipe (|) to using it in explode I don't know why php does not know it, and do not explode anything!

```
  $text=file_get_contents("1-40.txt");
  $explode=explode("।",$text);
  print_r($explode);
```

**What is the solution?**

***note: I don't know Bengali and Arabic**

Comment: Looks like every paragraph is also separated using newline characters! Don't they?

Comment: @someOne yes you are right, But there are about 400 sentences there and some of them having Enter between Bengali and Arabic

Comment: Actually, no. I believe that the character `।` is used to format the numbered list in Bengali (as the dot in English format, like the 1. 2. 3. etc) and at least in the example provided _all_ of the paragraphs are separated using newline characters isolating the Bengali and Arabic versions of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe check your file encoding or enviroment settings.

I just used a UTF-8 file, copied your text and it works "fine".

Have a look here.

http://3v4l.org/2doAg

`var_dump( explode('।', $text) );`

The char used as a delimiter is named [*devanagari danda*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danda) `0x964` / `&#2404;` - you can find it with some online unicode lookup tools like [this one](http://unicodelookup.com/#%E0%A5%A4/1)

Comment: Thank you. Can you please vote up for my question? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It is not PHP's fault, as it works well in [this demo](http://codepad.org/DUWFS3tP).

I would say that you have an encoding issue with that `.txt` file. Maybe you will just want to "explode" on numbers instead, using `preg_split()` :

[demo](http://codepad.org/AW4pqfcp)

```
preg_split("/\d\-/", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the character `।` is used to format the numbered list in Bengali (as the dot in English format, like the 1. 2. 3. etc) and at least in the example provided all of the paragraphs are separated using newline characters isolating the Bengali and Arabic versions of a sentence. So, to get the paragraphs separated you may use the following:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $txt));
var_dump($arr);
```